# How to save ManyToMany field in second database

Tags: django, django-models

I have two databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'db', 'sqlite.db'),
    },

    'slave': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'db', 'slave.db'),
    }

}
```

i have table with ManyToMany field:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Data(models.Model):
    xml     = models.TextField(max_length=90000)
    users   = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

when i run code:

```
for i in Data.objects.all():
    i.save(using='slave')
```

all entry from 'default' database appear in 'slave' without ManyToMany field users.
How can i explicitly copy users field to 'slave' database?

EDITED:

i try advice from Rohan:

```
for i in Data.objects.all():
    back_i = i
    # back_i.users.all().count() = 1
    i.save(using='slave')
    # back_i.users.all().count() = 0
    for u in back_i.users.all():
        i.users.add(u)
```

so i think solution is near, but not here

Answer (score 1):

django does not support cross database relations.

Extract from [cross database relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations)

*Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases. If you have used a router to partition models to different databases, any foreign key and many-to-many relationships defined by those models must be internal to a single database.*

However, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#moving-an-object-from-one-database-to-another) you can implement `post_save` signal for user to have same user record on `slave` database. But you will have to maintain that database consistency e.g. deleting user from both databases.

*Update:* to save `ManyToMany` in different db you can try this

```
for i in Data.objects.all():
    back_i = i
    i.save(using='slave')
    for u in back_i.users.all():
        i.users.add(u)
```

Comment: I have no problem moving models with foreignkey field from one db to another. The problem is only with ManyToMany field, because i can't explicitly resave django m2m relationship.

Comment: before i.save(using='slave') back_i.users.all().count() != 0 , and after save back_i.users.all().count() = 0, i think solution is  near

Comment: @Likeit, switch `back_i` and `i` to do the operations, i.e. `back_i.save(using='slave')`.

Comment: No, it does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to [rohan's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829036/4638824)... (it is assumed that 'User' already exists in slave database)

```
for item in Data.objects.all():

    new_item = item
    item_users = item.users.all()

    new_item.save(using='slave')

    for u in item_users:
       u2 = User.objects.using('slave').get(pk=u.id)
       new_item.users.add(u2)

    new_item.save(using='slave')
```

Comment: If you adapt code from another answer, you should include a link to that answer.